# How I make a shortcode for this code?

Tags: shortcode

I wrote a script to display recent posts from a specific category in wordPress.

```
<?php
$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=3&posts_per_page=10' );
while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
?>
<ul>
<li><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

<ul><li><?php the_content(); ?></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Now I want to make a short code for this code because I want to display recent categories in pages. I have no good idea about short codes. Can you please help me to create a shot code?

Comment: Have you reviewed the [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)? Or reviewed a [relevant example](http://generatewp.com/shortcodes/?clone=recent-posts-shortcode)?

Answer (score 1):

You should read the [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) as suggested. This should give you an overview of what is happening and how shortcodes should be used. One important thing to remember here, shortcode content should be returned, not echo'ed. Here is also a [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-shortcode-to-list-posts-with-multiple-parameters--wp-32199) that help me a lot.

Just a quick tip here, shortcodes should always go into a plugin. If you haven't yet created one, go and read [functionality plugin](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=functionality+plugin&oq=functionality&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59j69i60l2.6714j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

The correct way of constructing your shortcode would be. Your shortcode will be `[my-shortcode]` This is untested though

```
add_shortcode( 'my-shortcode', 'my_custom_query_shortcode' );
function my_custom_query_shortcode( $atts ) {
    ob_start();

$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=3&posts_per_page=10' );

 if ( $catquery->have_posts() ) : 
   while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
      ?>
      <ul>
        <li><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>   </h3>

        <ul>
           <li><?php the_content(); ?></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <?php 
      endwhile;

     $myvariable = ob_get_clean();

     return $myvariable;

 endif;    

}
```