# return wp query results in a shortcode

Tags: wp-query, shortcode

I am using `wp query` results in a shortcode, and right now I am echoing out the stuff I need, or just using wp functions (`title(), the_content() etc.`).

The problem is, if I put that shortcode in a post, and I put it on the top and write some text below the shortcode, the shortcode result is ALWAYS at the bottom.

I know that is because I have to RETURN values from a shortode, but how do I return the following?

```
// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

I tried appending each function and html to a variable and returning that, but I don't get the same result as when I do the above.

Comment: See [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/154871/31545)

Comment: Thanks, seems to be working! the only problem I have now is that it doesn't work if the shortcode is placed inside a text widget ( or to be more specific, the js plugin in the shortcode does not get activated it seems).

So, if I place the shortcode directly in a theme file (e.g. index.php) it works, if I place it inside a page/post it works, but in a text widget it does not work properly ( and it did before ). 

any idea?

Comment: Did you add support for shortcodes in text widgets. Please add your current code

Comment: Yes. I added the ob start right after the start of the function and it works now with text widget as well! Thank you so much.

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help. Enjoy :-)